# Redux action is failing after any page change/page load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt, redux-toolkit

I want to store the user's state through Redux, I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I am able to login and register successfully but when I try to do anything, like update my profile details or go to admin panel (from an admin account) the frontend gives me an error "Please Login to access this page" even though I am logged in (and this error is coming from the backend from isAuthenticatedUser), and my loadUser action gets failed. I also do not see the token in the application's tab of the browser window, but when I use a different window I can see the set-headers in the network's tab and there I can see the token and its expiration date. But I can't see the token in application' tab still on a different window.

This is my loadUser action:

```
  try {
    dispatch({ type: "LoadUserRequest" });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/me`);

    dispatch({ type: "LoadUserSuccess", payload: data.user });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "LoadUserFail", payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};
```

At first I thought there must be some token issue from the backend but I can see the token being generated when I do a logging statement.

This is my sendToken function:

```
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res, next) => {
  const token = user.getJWTToken();
console.log("from token.js", token)
  // options for cookie
  const options = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
   
  };

  res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    token,
  });

};
```

I can see the token in the terminal which comes from this above function (sendToken)

but If I try to do a logging statement for token coming from isAuthenticatedUser. it gets undedined

This is my isAuthnticatedUser function;

```
exports.isAuthenticatedUser = asyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  console.log("from auth.js", token);
  if (!token) {
    return next(new ErrorHandle("Please Login first to access this page", 400));
  }
  const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

  req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);

  next();
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: error.message,
  });
}
});
```

I am using it as a middleware like this,

```
router.route("/password/update").put(isAuthenticatedUser, updatePassword);
router.route("/me/update").put(isAuthenticatedUser, updateProfile);
```

I can provide more code if you want, please let me know.